# Target text of <a> if other elements are inside the tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible (and if so, how) to target only the text in an `<a>` tag? When I inspect it and hover over it it show `#text` even if I didn't assign any ID. But also I can't figure out how to target this `#text`.

What I want to achieve: On hover underline only the text, but not the arrow next to it. I also tried the `not selector` but had no luck with it.

The has to be in the `<a>` so the user can also click the arrow. Unfortunately I have no access to wrap the text in a `span` or something else.

```css
.class_A {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.class_A:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.class_B:before {
  content:">"
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="class_A">Some Text
  <i class="class_B">
  </i> 
 </a>
```

Comment: you can  span your  <i> tag

Comment: A solution without moving out the `<i>` tag will always be a little hacky imo. Why can't you move it out? Maybe work on this?

Comment: @ShayanKanwal I can't edit the html. It's cms generated content and I don't have access to the core files, only css, js etc.